# Au point que / à tel point que

Tags: sens, conjonctions

> Le niveau de l'eau est arrivé **à tel point que** les quais de la ville
> sont inondés. ([source](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0%20tel%20point%20que))
>
> Les ouvriers ne se sentaient pas écoutés **au point qu**'ils ont décidé
> d'arrêter la production. ([source](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/au%20point%20que))

Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_point_que) et Antidote disent que *à tel point que* et *au point que* sont synonymes. Donc, ils devraient être interchangeables dans les phrases citées. Et pourtant, j'ai l'impression qu'il y a une petite différence de sens, mais je n'arrive pas à m'expliquer.

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve la première phrase incorrecte, le verbe arriver étant peu compatible avec une intensité (le niveau arrive ou n'arrive pas mais on ne dit pas "le niveau arrive beaucoup"). J'aurais donc écrit :

> Le niveau de l'eau est arrivé **à un point tel** que les quais de la ville sont inondés.

ou

> Le niveau de l'eau a augmenté **à** (un) **tel point** que les quais de la ville sont inondés.

ou

> L'eau est arrivée/montée **à un tel niveau** que les quais de la ville sont inondés.

Dans la deuxième phrase, les deux locutions sont pour moi utilisables sans différence de sens.

Comment: J'aime le plus la 3ème phrase _L'eau est montée à un tel niveau que les quais de la ville sont inondés_. Et quelle est la différence entre _à un point tel que_ et _à (un) tel point que_ ? J'ai trouvé [ceci](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wordt/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9iAF2Pg2faNc.html), mais j'ai du mal à saisir cette différence.

Comment: La forme *est arrivé à un point tel que* n'implique pas une intensité qui sort de l'ordinaire. On dit juste que c'est arrivé à un niveau donné et que ça a eu une conséquence. La phrase n'est pas terrible mais j'ai essayé de préserver au maximum l'original. Au contraire, *à un tel point* implique une forte intensité. Ça marche avec un niveau de l'eau qui augmente car l'intensité de cette augmentation a un sens, mais ça ne passe pas pour moi avec un niveau d'eau qui arrive car cette arrivée est plus du tout ou rien que quelque chose de variable.

Comment: Si on reprend ces phrases avec *tellement*, plus courant, on arrive à 1. *le niveau de l'eau a tellement augmenté que ça a débordé*, correct et 2. *le niveau de l'eau est tellement arrivé que ça a débordé* (??)